# Change .fasta file name

Tags: text-processing

I have something like 2000 fasta files with a structure like this:

```
Name_ID#_Name2_ID1...2000.fasta
```

I want to change the order of the filename to this:

```
Name2.Name_ID#_ID1...2000.fasta
```

Does someone have a suggestion on how I can achieve that?

Comment: Read `man rename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to attack this problem.  One approach is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.fasta; do
    tokens=( $(echo "${i}" | sed -e 's/_/ /g') )
    newName="${tokens[2]}.${tokens[0]}_${tokens[1]}_${tokens[3]}'"

    echo "mv ${i} ${newName}"
done
```

This script loops over each file in the current directory that ends in `.fasta`; each time through the loop, the variable `${i}` contains the current filename.

Next, the script uses `sed` to change underscores (`_`) to spaces in the filename, and stores that as an array of tokens.  For a file named  `Name_ID1_Name2_ID1000.fasta`, you end up with:

```
tokens[0]='Name'
tokens[1]='ID1'
tokens[2]='Name2'
tokens[3]='ID1000.fasta'
```

Next, the script creates the `newName` based on those tokens and your description of the order you want.  Finally, the script prints the `mv` command it would use to perform the rename.

If you run the script, it'll print what it would do.  You can inspect that to make sure that it's behaving the way you want.  If so, then you can remove the `echo`:

```bsh
mv "${i}" "${newName}"
```

and run it again.  With that, it'll actually perform the rename.